# Getting Null in location in facebook login iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I'm building an iOS app using storyboards.I have integrated facebook login in my app,i'm facing a 
problem I'm getting all user profile information like name,image and gender etc.But in location i'm getting null.

Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)fbLogin:(id)sender {
  if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpen
        || FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpenTokenExtended) {
    [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
     //  If the session state is not any of the two "open" states when the button is clicked
    } else {
        // Open a session showing the user the login UI
        // You must ALWAYS ask for public_profile permissions when opening a session
        [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"email",@"user_location",@"user_birthday",@"user_hometown",@"current city"]
                                           allowLoginUI:YES
                                      completionHandler:
         ^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
           switch (state) {
                 case FBSessionStateOpen:[[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {
                    if (error) {
                      NSLog(@"error:%@",error);
                   }
                     else
                     {
                     [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *FBuser, NSError *error) {
                             if (error) {
                                 // Handle error
                             }

                             else {
                                 NSString *userName = [FBuser name];
                                 NSLog(@"username===%@",userName);
                                 NSLog(@"sesseion=%@",session);
                             }
                         }];

                         id<FBGraphUser> fbUser = (id<FBGraphUser>)user;
                         id<FBGraphPlace> fbPlace = [fbUser location];
                         id<FBGraphLocation> fbLocation = [fbPlace location];
                         NSString * userCity = [fbLocation city];
                         NSString * userCountry = [fbLocation country];
                         NSString * userZip = [fbLocation zip];
                         NSLog(@"userCity=%@",userCity);//getting null

                         NSLog(@"FB user first name:%@",user.first_name);
                         userName=user.first_name;
                         NSLog(@"FB user last name:%@",user.last_name);
//                       NSLog(@"FB user birthday:%@",user.birthday);
                         NSLog(@"FB user location:%@",user.location);//getting null here
                         NSLog(@"FB user username:%@",user.username);
                         NSLog(@"FB user gender:%@",[user objectForKey:@"gender"]);
                         NSLog(@"email id:%@",[user objectForKey:@"email"]);
                         NSLog(@"location:%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Location: %@\n\n",
                                                user.location[@"name"]]);
```

Comment: Are you testing in simulator? Try and test in device and you'll get the location.

Comment: Hi @KananVora thanks for quick reply,i have tested on real device also but getting the same result.

Comment: What you have imported for using facebook ? i mean which framework?

Comment: @KananVora I have imported facebook sdk into my project and #import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h> this in my class.

Comment: @Hitesh You have custom privacy settings at my location field in facebook.